# How to create a TextView with a PreferenceCategory layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How do I create a `TextView` with a `PreferenceCategory` layout?

Example:
[image: Example]

I can't use the PreferenceCategory because it is not in a PreferenceActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option was to use a TextView and add the following lines:

```
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
```